# Error then running EXE from resource

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have a two WinForms NET application "Test.exe" at which the resource "WindowsFormsApplication1.exe". Resource is marked as "embedded." The program resource - blank project Winforms (only form and a button without a handler). Use common code in "Test.exe":

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            RunInternalExe("WindowsFormsApplication1.exe");
        }
   private static void RunInternalExe(string exeName)
        {
            //Get the current assembly
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            //Get the assembly's root name
            string rootName = assembly.GetName().Name;

            //Get the resource stream
            Stream resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(rootName + "." + exeName);

            //Verify the internal exe exists
            if (resourceStream == null)
                return;

            //Read the raw bytes of the resource
            byte[] resourcesBuffer = new byte[resourceStream.Length];

            resourceStream.Read(resourcesBuffer, 0, resourcesBuffer.Length);
            resourceStream.Close();

            //Load the bytes as an assembly
            Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(resourcesBuffer);

            //Execute the assembly
            exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null); //no parameters
        }
```

When trying to run the EXE from the resource falls out with the error:
"TargetInvocationException" on the line:

```
 exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: Do provide more details about the Exception. What's the full message? Can you show the stack trace? Does it have an inner exception?

Comment: Sorry for translate, I have russain VS. Inner exeption - "Before the creation of the first object IWin32Window the application should call SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault." Maybe something to do with the coincidence of names? For example "Program.cs" in both programms.

Comment: Actually the Exception message already leads you to a solution. I don't think it's a name problem, I think you should search for a solution that has to do with the `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Form in resource program was created in the same thread. In this case I need to use code like this:

```js
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        this.Hide();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RunInternalExe));
        t.Start("RunCodeFromDll.exe");

        //RunInternalExe("RunCodeFromDll.exe");
        }
    static void RunInternalExe(object tempName)
        {
        string exeName = tempName.ToString();
        //Get the current assembly
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        //Get the assembly's root name
        string rootName = assembly.GetName().Name;

        //Get the resource stream
        Stream resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(rootName + "." + exeName);

        //Verify the internal exe exists
        if (resourceStream == null)
            return;

        //Read the raw bytes of the resource
        byte[] resourcesBuffer = new byte[resourceStream.Length];

        resourceStream.Read(resourcesBuffer, 0, resourcesBuffer.Length);
        resourceStream.Close();

        //Load the bytes as an assembly
        Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(resourcesBuffer);

        //Execute the assembly
        exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null); //.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null); //no parameters
        }
```

I should be more careful. )))